# How can I access the value of a pandas dataframe and assign it to a variable as its original TYPE (rather than a Series)?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
source            timestamp 
  'n'        2022-11-11 06:00:00
  'y'        2022-12-11 06:00:00
  't'        2022-13-11 06:00:00
```

Let's say I want to assign the middle `timestamp` (`2022-12-11 06:00:00`) to a variable `time`. How would I do this?

I've tried:

```
time = df.loc[df['source' == df['y'], 'timestamp']
```

The issue is that now `time` is a `Series`, which is expected.

But is there a way to retrieve the middle timestamp as its original type, which is a Timestamp?

Comment: `df.loc[df['source'] == "'y'", 'timestamp'].values[0]`

Comment: Great suggestion, but the index may not be 0

Comment: Even in the above case you would get a key error.

Comment: even the above case is based on your current posted input

Comment: Is there a way to do it without indexing?

Comment: your words are vague: you started with "to retrieve the **middle** timestamp", then proceeded with "the index may not be 0".

Comment: Well your assumption is that the index is 0, that is quite a big assumption! Especially since in most cases the index will not be 0... after all we are accessing the MIDDLE timestamp, which will have index 1. 
But I take your point on clarifying the index.

Comment: you have confused row index (when you said "MIDDLE timestamp, which will have index 1") and `values[0]` - that's different

Comment: Ohhh I did not see the `.values[0]`,please accept my apologies sir. It does work. I just added `[0]` to the end of my code, which is clearly wrong.